# How can we switch the theme in Ionic App from Lighter version to darker version ?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have two CSS file generated, One for lighter Version and other for darker Version. So please let me know how can i maintain two theme for same App?

Any idea how can we implement it on ionic app using theme toggled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8wLeg32ATZAK7V4oQww0?p=preview)

You can easily toggle between CSS files.

**index.html**:

1. set your `ng-app` on the `HTML` tag:

   ```
   <html ng-app="starter">
   ```
2. dynamically set your style:

   ```
   <link ng-href="{{style}}" rel="stylesheet">
   ```

**app.js**: define your default style in `run`:

```
$rootScope.style = "css/style.css";
```

**controllers.js**: add your toggle style logic:

```
//All available styles
$scope.styles = [
  {
    name: "Default",
    url: "style.css"
  },
  {
    name: "Dark",
    url: "dark-style.css"
  }
];

/**
 * Change the style.
 * @param style The selected style.
 */
$scope.changeStyle = function(style){
  $rootScope.style = "css/" + style.url;
};
```

**view.html**: attach the related `HTML`:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
  <div class="input-label">
    Style
  </div>
  <select ng-options="style as style.name for style in styles" ng-change="changeStyle(style)" ng-model="style">
  </select>
</label>
```