# Switching theme color in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-style

I am using royal color for all my tabs /nav-view. I have a setting tab that will all the user to switch the theme color by choosing one of the radio buttons. For example, if the user chooses the dark theme, all tab colors will switch to dark. How I can do this?

```
<ion-view view-title="Setting">

<ion-content >

  <h3 class="background-color:royal; padding">App Color</h3>
   <ion-list>
     <ion-radio class="royal"name="group" value="b1">
     Purple
     <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
   </ion-radio>
    <ion-radio class="dark" name="group" value="b2">
      Dark
       <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
     </ion-radio>
     <ion-radio class="calm" name="group" value="b3">
       Light
 <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
     </ion-radio>
   </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we switch the theme in Ionic App from Lighter version to darker version ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228693/how-can-we-switch-the-theme-in-ionic-app-from-lighter-version-to-darker-version)

Answer (score 0):

Save the selected theme in local storage and use ng-class to dynamically apply style

```
 $scope.themeChange = function (theme) {
        // save theme locally
        $window.localStorage.appTheme = theme;
}

<ion-header-bar ng-class="'bar-' + appTheme">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic - Switch Themes</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate because I didn't get it ?