# why does Color Theming App back to default when reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

**THE CASE**

so I've followed this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228693/how-can-we-switch-the-theme-in-ionic-app-from-lighter-version-to-darker-version)  and it works well, even when changing page. But, I get back to default when page reloaded, I figured out how to save this setting (even locally) and when reload it won't change until the user change it only at setting section. I tried some method save with $window.localstorage but it didn't work.

```
  $scope.styles = [
          {
            name: "Default",
            url: "style.css"
          },
          {
            name: "Positive",
            url: "positive.css"
          },
          {
            name: "Energized",
            url: "energized.css"
          },
          {
            name: "Fire",
            url: "fire.css"
          },
          {
            name: "Mint",
            url: "mint.css"
          },
          {
            name: "Violet",
            url: "violet.css"
          },
          {
            name: "Grass",
            url: "grass.css"
          },
          {
            name: "Pink",
            url: "pink.css"
          },
          {
            name: "Dark",
            url: "dark-style.css"
          }
        ];

        /**
         * Change the style.
         * @param style The selected style.
         */
        $scope.changeStyle = function(style){
          if (style) {
          $rootScope.style = "css/" + style.url;
          $window.localStorage.styles = style;

        } else {
          $rootScope.style = "css/style.css"
        }
        };
```

and this is the way I call them

```
<label class="item item-input ic-selected">
            <a class="icon icon-right ion-locked" style="margin-right: 10px;"></a>
            <select ng-options="style as style.name for style in styles" ng-change="changeStyle(style)" ng-model="style" >sadas
        </select>
          </label>
```

[image]

**Question**

How do I save style input from ng-options to localstorage so I can call them when page reloaded/refreshed ?

Comment: setting values for localStorage inside controllers may not be good idea...Use factory and check if localStorage is already set and if not update the localStorage...there are quite a few angular modules which make it easy to use local storage..

Comment: can you direct me to reference please?

Comment: Sure... One module which is extensively used is https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage   ... There are many other modules out there...But this one in particular has exhaustive documentation...